# $M\otimes_A N\cong A$ implies $M$ is left $A$-projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, projective-module

Let $A$ be an algebra (possibly non-commutative). Let $M,N$ be $A-A$-bimodules. Suppose that $M\otimes_AN\cong A$. Can we conclude that $M$ is left $A$-projective?

I tried many things but ultimately failed to prove this. It is worth noting though that $N$ should inject into the dual of $M$ (I think) and that $(N\otimes_A M)^{\otimes 2}\cong N\otimes_A M$. These things look useful.

Comment: If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity, and $M \otimes_R N \cong R$ , then $M$ is finitely generated projective $R$-module of rank $1$. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFW